# I Can't Search Through An API in python

Tags: python, json, api

I am trying to look through a data set in Python, but I can't seem to search through it. I believe it's because of how it is written, there are square brackets at the beginning. I have tried a bunch of things off of the top of my head and from googling things. I have tried other APIs and they work fine but it is specifically the one I want to use that is the problem. I am also a beginner, so I am not sure exactly what the issue is and how to fix it.

The following is the API data

```
[
  {
    "actual_time": 1679865425,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 118,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc1305",
          "frc4152",
          "frc6864"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 105,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc2013",
          "frc610",
          "frc771"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "f",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_f1m1",
    "match_number": 1,
    "predicted_time": 1679865483,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679862660,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679866919,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 134,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc1305",
          "frc4152",
          "frc6864"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 123,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc2013",
          "frc610",
          "frc771"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "f",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_f1m2",
    "match_number": 2,
    "predicted_time": 1679866847,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679863860,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679765029,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 118,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc865",
          "frc610",
          "frc4069"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 31,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc6865",
          "frc8731",
          "frc6864"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm11",
    "match_number": 11,
    "predicted_time": 1679765069,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679764500,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679770411,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 68,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc5672",
          "frc610",
          "frc8731"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 75,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc5834",
          "frc4069",
          "frc7757"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm15",
    "match_number": 15,
    "predicted_time": 1679770409,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679770260,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679773081,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 108,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc1305",
          "frc6864",
          "frc610"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 65,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc1374",
          "frc2706",
          "frc6514"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm19",
    "match_number": 19,
    "predicted_time": 1679773125,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679772420,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679777798,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 99,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc1374",
          "frc610",
          "frc6110"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 69,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc7476",
          "frc771",
          "frc4069"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm28",
    "match_number": 28,
    "predicted_time": 1679777787,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679777280,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679760499,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 18,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc5870",
          "frc6864",
          "frc771"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 128,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc610",
          "frc5834",
          "frc2013"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm3",
    "match_number": 3,
    "predicted_time": 1679760701,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679760180,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679779249,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 84,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc6110",
          "frc1305",
          "frc3543"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 92,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc6987",
          "frc610",
          "frc771"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm31",
    "match_number": 31,
    "predicted_time": 1679779300,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679778900,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679781576,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 96,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc3543",
          "frc6865",
          "frc610"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 92,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc6864",
          "frc4152",
          "frc865"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm36",
    "match_number": 36,
    "predicted_time": 1679781639,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679781600,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679784078,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 126,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc4152",
          "frc1374",
          "frc610"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 76,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc865",
          "frc6859",
          "frc8729"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm40",
    "match_number": 40,
    "predicted_time": 1679784090,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679783760,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679841027,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 106,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc4069",
          "frc4152",
          "frc6865"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 92,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc610",
          "frc7757",
          "frc1334"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm46",
    "match_number": 46,
    "predicted_time": 1679841128,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679841000,
    "winning_alliance": "blue"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679843656,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 21,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc1334",
          "frc9127",
          "frc5834"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 128,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc610",
          "frc2708",
          "frc7476"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm51",
    "match_number": 51,
    "predicted_time": 1679843768,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679843700,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679845719,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 66,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc5672",
          "frc6987",
          "frc7757"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 95,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc610",
          "frc771",
          "frc2708"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm54",
    "match_number": 54,
    "predicted_time": 1679845743,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679845320,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679762321,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 62,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc3560",
          "frc5834",
          "frc865"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 87,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc6859",
          "frc5870",
          "frc610"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "qm",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_qm6",
    "match_number": 6,
    "predicted_time": 1679762380,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679761800,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679861979,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 76,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc7476",
          "frc5870",
          "frc1374"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 113,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc2013",
          "frc610",
          "frc771"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "sf",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_sf11m1",
    "match_number": 1,
    "predicted_time": 1679862043,
    "set_number": 11,
    "time": 1679859720,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679854067,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 101,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc7757",
          "frc3543",
          "frc6865"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 117,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc610",
          "frc2013",
          "frc771"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "sf",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_sf1m1",
    "match_number": 1,
    "predicted_time": 1679854106,
    "set_number": 1,
    "time": 1679853600,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  },
  {
    "actual_time": 1679857964,
    "alliances": {
      "blue": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 113,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc2706",
          "frc4069",
          "frc1246"
        ]
      },
      "red": {
        "dq_team_keys": [],
        "score": 125,
        "surrogate_team_keys": [],
        "team_keys": [
          "frc2013",
          "frc610",
          "frc771"
        ]
      }
    },
    "comp_level": "sf",
    "event_key": "2023onnob",
    "key": "2023onnob_sf7m1",
    "match_number": 1,
    "predicted_time": 1679857989,
    "set_number": 7,
    "time": 1679857080,
    "winning_alliance": "red"
  }
]
```

And here is the code I am currently trying

```
import requests
import json
payload = {'score':118}
response = requests.get("https://www.thebluealliance.com/api/v3/team/frc610/event/2023onnob/matches/simple",
headers={"X-TBA-Auth-Key":"XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"},params=payload)
print(response.json())
 data = response.text
 parse_json = json.loads(data)
 active_case = parse_json['alliances']['red']['team_keys[1]']
  print("Active cases in South Andaman:", active_case)
```

Comment: Your data is an array, so you would index each item with a number: `parse_json[0]['alliances']['red']['team_keys'][1]`